# How do I make a viewController appear when app loads?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've got a working app that doesn't crash and I've set my initial VC to be the one I want. When running on the simulator, my app opens for the first time on the VC I want, but if I go to; Hardware -> Home and click on the app again on the main iPhone menu, the app loads the VC I left with and not the VC I set an my main. I'm new to iOS development so I don't understand what's not working. Other questions's answers don't help me a bit since my main VC is set on my storyboard. Thanks for the help guys! This is in my appDelegate file:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"appWillResignActive", name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

    func appWillResignActive() -> () {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(ViewController, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: that's just the way an iPhone works, the app is sent to background and it keeps the state as it is. I assume there are ways of achieving what you want but that's just default behaviour right there, not an error of any kind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and call a method right before the app goes to the background, to set the VC to the one you want. This way, once they re-open the app, it should be where you want it to be.

**Obj-C:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillResignActive) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];

-(void) appWillResignActive {
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:<UIViewController you want> animated:NO];
}
```

**SWIFT:**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"appWillResignActive", name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

func appWillResignActive() -> () {
    self.navigationController.popToViewController(<UIViewController you want>, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: He is using Swift, not Obj-C.

Comment: It's the same thing... Ok I'll "translate" it to Swift.

Comment: Should I call this method in my appDelegate or in a specific VC?

Comment: I've been trying to figure out your solution, but I can't get it to work. I'll post my changes in my question

Comment: Oh! I didn't mean for you to put it in AppDelegate. Sorry I mixed this question up with another question...

You should put the first line in `viewDidLoad()` of the VC you want to show, then put `appWillResignActive()` among the other methods of the same VC.

Comment: Haha that's alright. I was confused but now that makes sense. I'll try this solution. Thanks a lot!